# Using purrr or igraph (or any other method instead of nested loops) to generate all possible combinations of directed connections?

Tags: r, igraph, tidyverse, purrr

I have a dataset that has this sort of a structure:

```
df
#>   Instance Alice_prefers Bob_prefers Charlie_prefers
#> 1        1           Bob     Charlie           Alice
#> 2        2           Bob       Alice             Bob
#> 3        3           Bob     Charlie             Bob
```

My desired output would be a dataframe where:

- every row of the dataframe is one combination of Alice, Bob and Charlie's possible preferences
- the dataframe contains all possible combinations, i.e. the number of rows in the dataframe is equal to the number of possible combinations.
- in any given combination (i.e. row), a person prefers one other person, and they cannot prefer themselves, i.e. Alice can choose to prefer Bob or Charlie, but cannot prefer Alice, and cannot prefer Bob *and* Charlie in the same instance.

  The complete desired output is thus:

```
#>   instance alice_prefers bob_prefers charlie_prefers
#> 1        1           Bob       Alice           Alice
#> 2        2           Bob       Alice             Bob
#> 3        3           Bob     Charlie           Alice
#> 4        4           Bob     Charlie             Bob
#> 5        5       Charlie       Alice           Alice
#> 6        6       Charlie       Alice             Bob
#> 7        7       Charlie     Charlie           Alice
#> 8        8       Charlie     Charlie             Bob
```

My current solution works (code below), but seems extremely clunky, and doesn't obviously generalise to more people than just Alice, Bob and Charlie (k = 3). I'm using nested loops.

I have two questions:

1. There must be a simpler way to generate this output, either with `purrr` or `igraph` or something else--is there a better way to do it? I haven't used `igraph` before.
2. Currently, the problem is for 3 people `(k = 3)`: Alice, Bob, Charlie. Is there some way I can easily generalise the solution to add more people, so that if I wanted to generate the combinations for say Alice, Bob, Charlie, Don, and Enid, I could just call a function where I pass the `k = 5` as an argument? The names of the people can be anything, I've just set them to follow the alphabet to help me work with this.

```
choices_alice <- c("Bob", "Charlie")
choices_bob <- c("Alice", "Charlie")
choices_charlie <- c("Alice", "Bob")

get_combinations <- function(choices_alice, choices_bob, choices_charlie) {
  instance <- numeric()
  alice_prefers <- character()
  bob_prefers <- character()
  charlie_prefers <- character()
  id <- 1
  for (a_counter in seq_along(choices_alice)) {
    for (b_counter in seq_along(choices_bob)){
      for (c_counter in seq_along(choices_charlie)){
        alice_prefers[id] <- choices_alice[a_counter]
        bob_prefers[id] <- choices_bob[b_counter]
        charlie_prefers[id] <- choices_charlie[c_counter]
        instance[id] <- id
        id <- id + 1
      }

    }
  }
  data.frame(instance, alice_prefers, bob_prefers, charlie_prefers, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}

df <- get_combinations(choices_alice, choices_bob, choices_charlie)
df
```

Comment: Do you need `expand.grid(choices_alice, choices_bob, choices_charlie)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `crossing` function from tidyr (or `expand.grid` in base) can turn several vectors into a table of all combinatons.

But to get your solution to extend to any number of nodes (and ensure that each node doesn't include itself), you might want to use a bit of purrr as well.

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

# Can be any number of nodes
nodes <- c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie")

# Create a list: for each node, what are all other nodes
possible_nodes <- map(nodes, ~ setdiff(nodes, .))
names(possible_nodes) <- nodes

# Call tidyr's crossing on all of these arguments
crossing(!!!possible_nodes)
```

Note that `!!!` tells crossing that you want to call it with all of the arguments in that list, so it's similar to `crossing(Alice = --, Bob = --, Charlie = --)`.

---

The above code works for any number of nodes. For instance, setting `nodes` to

```
nodes <- c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "Dave", "Eric", "Frank")
```

leads to the result

```
# A tibble: 15,625 x 6
   Alice Bob   Charlie Dave  Eric  Frank  
   <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>  
 1 Bob   Alice Alice   Alice Alice Alice  
 2 Bob   Alice Alice   Alice Alice Bob    
 3 Bob   Alice Alice   Alice Alice Charlie
 4 Bob   Alice Alice   Alice Alice Dave   
 5 Bob   Alice Alice   Alice Alice Eric   
 6 Bob   Alice Alice   Alice Bob   Alice  
 7 Bob   Alice Alice   Alice Bob   Bob    
 8 Bob   Alice Alice   Alice Bob   Charlie
 9 Bob   Alice Alice   Alice Bob   Dave   
10 Bob   Alice Alice   Alice Bob   Eric   
# … with 15,615 more rows
```

Comment: Should the line be `possible_nodes <- map(nodes, ~ setdiff(nodes, .))`, rather than `possible_nodes <- map(nodes, ~ setdiff(people, .))`? Thank you to both Dave and Ronak. I should let you both know that your respective bodies of work have made my life a lot better and happier, so thank you. Of course, Stack Overflow will ask me to delete this part of the comment, and I will.

Comment: I wonder what the `!!!` in `crossing(!!!possible_nodes)` does? I've tried Googling, but Google keeps ignoring the punctutation marks.

Comment: The triple exclamation is a function to modify the Non Standard Evaluation in `dplyr` which is a deep rabbit hole. More info at https://johnmackintosh.com/2018-02-19-theory-free-tidyeval/

Comment: @JeremyK. Yes, it should have been `nodes` rather than `people` (fixed). I've also tried adding an explanation of `!!!`. Glad that it helped you!